# How can I override Django Admin page?

Tags: python, django, overriding, admin

I've read many answers but I don't know what am I missing.
I did the same steps as they are mentioned in Django Docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) but nothing happened.

Here is my actual configuration :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app1.apps.App1Config',
    'app2.apps.App2Config',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'rida.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],#i modified this line
        'APP_DIRS': False, #True
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

the contents of admin.py file of app1 :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from app1.models import Modele

admin.site.register(Modele)
```

I want to override the template base.html, so I copied it from django\contrib\admin\templates\admin and put it in myproject\templates\admin\app1, then I made some changes on this file but nothing happened, so I have no idea why it doesn't work and what am I missing.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean overriding `base_site.html`?

Comment: base_site.html extends base.html, but i wanna override any template of admin pages, i just took base.html as an exemple